# Transforme as linhas de uma coluna - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, oracle11g

Alguém me ajuda com a seguinte questão.

Gerar arquivo de extensão “.sql” com script que transforme as linhas de
uma coluna em uma variável string, com seus valores separadas por
vírgulas, exemplo:
De:
col1
linha 1
linha 2
linha 3

Para:
col1
"linha1, linha2, linha3"

Preferência em T-SQL.

Comment: Harry, bem vindo ao StackOVerflow pt-Br. Recomendo a leitura no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender um pouco mais de como as coisas funcionam por aqui.

Comment: Pela sua outra sua pergunta, vejo que está iniciando com `Sql`, recomendo esse curso [Learn SQL](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-sql) promovido pela CodCademy. Quando terminá-lo, recomendo esse que é um pouco mais avançado[SQL: Table Transformation](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/sql-table-transformation)